# Vert.x way of launching an app and config file

Tags: java, vert.x

I still have some misunderstanding about the way vertx suppose you'll deploy/start yor app. Still there are two questions, but they are hardly related for me.

***Question 1:*** *I there a way to make your app launchable from both: command line and IDEA?*

In one hand there is a [`Starter`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Starter.html) class (provided by Vert.x) to launch our application from command line. It provides `main` method for you. But if I launch it from  shell I won't have an ability to debug it, right?

In other hand to lanch your app in IDEA you need to create main method manually. Also [some features like configurations file](http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-application-configuration/index.html) are described only for command line way. I.e. `java -jar target/my-first-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar -conf src/main/conf/my-application-conf.json`

***Question 2:*** *How to set configuration file programmatically?*

I have a `ServerVerticle`, all questions there:

```
public class ServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    //QUESTION 1: I need this method for IDEA debugging, but don't need when launch app from command line. How to be??
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<Vertx> runner = vertx -> {
            try {
                vertx.deployVerticle("server.ServerVerticle", new DeploymentOptions());
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions());
        runner.accept(vertx);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        vertx.deployVerticle(...); //deploy another verticles
        //QUESTION 2: how to pass configuration file programmaticaly in vertx? I can parse json file with java I/O, but if some configs are used accross the whole app?
        vertx.createNetServer()
             .connectHandler(this::handleMessage)
             .listen(8080, "localhost");
    }
   

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to run your application from IntelliJ all you need to do is to add a run configuration where:

- main class: io.vertx.core.Launcher
- arguments: run ServerVerticle -conf /path/to/your/config.json

In order to set the configuration programmatically you need to pass a Json object to your deployment options as explained on the [javadocs](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/DeploymentOptions.html#setConfig-io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject-).